# compare-object issue using powershell

Tags: powershell, compare

looking for the best way to compare two system.objects. tried the compare-object option, doesn't seem to give the desired output..

```
> $abc
BGP summary information for VRF default
Router identifier 192.168.0.3, local AS number 7251
Neighbor Status Codes: m - Under maintenance
  Neighbor         V  AS           MsgRcvd   MsgSent  InQ OutQ  Up/Down State  PfxRcd PfxAcc
  10.12.103.119    4  7251               0         0    0    0    5d23h Connect
  10.46.252.121    4  7251               0         0    0    0    5d23h Connect

> $def
BGP summary information for VRF default
Router identifier 192.168.0.3, local AS number 7251
Neighbor Status Codes: m - Under maintenance
  Neighbor         V  AS           MsgRcvd   MsgSent  InQ OutQ  Up/Down State  PfxRcd PfxAcc
  10.12.103.119    4  7251               0         0    0    0    5d23h Active
  10.46.252.121    4  7251               0         0    0    0    5d23h Estab 

> $abc.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object

> $def.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object

> Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $abc -DifferenceObject $def

InputObject
-----------
BGP summary information for VRF default...
BGP summary information for VRF default...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're dealing with *strings* (`[System.String]`), not `[System.Objects]` - the latter is only the *base type*, i.e., what `[System.String]` *derives from*.

The best way to compare 2 multiline strings is to compare them line by line, and to that end you must split them into an array of lines:

```
PS> Compare-Object ($abc -split '\r?\n') ($def -split '\r?\n') 

InputObject                                                                     SideIndicator
-----------                                                                     -------------
  10.12.103.119    4  7251               0         0    0    0    5d23h Active  =>           
  10.46.252.121    4  7251               0         0    0    0    5d23h Estab   =>           
  10.12.103.119    4  7251               0         0    0    0    5d23h Connect <=           
  10.46.252.121    4  7251               0         0    0    0    5d23h Connect <=
```

The `=>` lines (the `.SideIndicator` property value of the output objects representing differences) indicate lines exclusive to the RHS (`$def`) whereas `<=` indicates lines exclusive to the LHS (`$abc`)

Comment: seems manual it eyeball and compare if there are multiple lines, is there any other option?

Comment: Each output line with `<=` or `=>` above is an _object_ that you can process _programmatically_, so the question is: what representation of the differences are you looking for? Please update your question directly.

Comment: yea need to scrub through programmatically. Should be easy, thanks for the advice, appreciate it.